# The file is saved but not showing with ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, kotlin, download, retrofit, storage

I download a file using Retrofit and save it in a subfolder in the download directory.

when I check with the phone's file manager, it is downloaded and saved correctly. For example, in the following path:
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path + "/MyApp"

But when I open the file manager with intent like ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the downloaded file is not visible.
In addition, if I rename the file or copy and paste it through the phone's file manager, everything will be fixed in the same path

Also, saving in the downloads folder is done without any problem
But when the subfolder is created and it is supposed to be saved there, this problem occurs

There is no problem with downloading by DownloadManager, but i want use retofit

Download function:

```
    suspend fun download(url: String, targetPath: String, progressRetrofit: RetrofitProgress) = flow {
    try {
        val response = apiService.download(url).awaitResponse()
        val body = response.body()
        if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
            try {
                val file = File(targetPath)
                body.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                    FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
                        val data = ByteArray(1024)
                        var read: Int
                        var currentDownloadSize = 0L
                        val fileSize = body.contentLength()
                        while (inputStream.read(data).also { read = it } != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(data, 0, read)
                            currentDownloadSize += read
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
                            {
                                progressRetrofit.onProgressUpdate((currentDownloadSize * 100 / fileSize).toInt(), fileSize, currentDownloadSize)
                            }
                        }
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
                        {
                            progressRetrofit.onProgressUpdate((currentDownloadSize * 100 / fileSize).toInt(), fileSize, currentDownloadSize)
                        }
                        outputStream.close()
                        outputStream.flush()
                    }
                }
                emit(NetworkResult.Success(true))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(NetworkResult.Failure(e.message.toString()))
                errorMessage(e.message.toString(), true)
            }
        } else {
            emit(NetworkResult.Failure(response.message()))
            errorMessage(response.errorBody().toString(), true)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(NetworkResult.Failure(e.message.toString()))
        errorMessage(e.message.toString(), true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share code where you would like to share your file.

Comment: I just dont believe your scenario.

Comment: @Gleichmut I don't want to share a file.
I want to view my file when I open the storage through the application.
Telegram file picker does not find my file either, but my file exists and opens.

Comment: @blackapps The file is stored in a sub-folder of the downloads , but it cannot be identified through the application file picker. But if I save it in my downloads folder, the file will be identified with the file picker.
Is this unbelivable???

Comment: @mahdi asd, please share your target SDK and test device (Vendor, model and android version). Could you please share a url where we also could download this file? Could you please confirm this behaviour is reproduced with any other file? Could you please confirm this behaviour is reproduce on Android 6 and Android 11 emulators?

Comment: @Gleichmut 
targetSdk is 32 
And this problem exists on all devices, including emulators and real phones.

Like Xiaomi Mi 8 Lite and Android 7, 11 and 12

And with every downloaded file

I guess the problem is not related to the type of phone, because there is no problem when we save it in the downloads folder. There is a problem when it is saved in a subfolder. Even this problem does not exist when it is done with the download manager of Android itself.
The problem is not the way to use the Intent. Because Telegram does not show a file in the sub-folder path.

Comment: `the file will be identified with the file picker. Is this unbelivable???` No. It is unbelievable that it is NOT found by ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT if that file indeed is in that subfolder of public Download directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm...

You are right...

It happens.

But only if with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT the user directly uses the `Downloads` item.

Instead the user should browse the device, and go to `Download` directory and then to the subdirectory.

(Note: The first ends with an s, the real directory is without s.).

After some more tests it appeared if the file was scanned by the MediaStore.

So add some few lines of code to let it be scanned after download.

Comment: Thank you very much It was absolutely true.
 And by using MediaScannerConnection, files can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 6.0 there are [bunch of changes](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file) in file sharing behaviour.

Please take a look on `FileProvider` and look further through API changes in the official android documentation, e.g. like [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Without extra details in your code or even reproducible code sample I can not help more.

Comment: Sharing? This is about ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Nothing more.